# How to have images go to the next line if they dont fit

Tags: android

I am using Linear layout with horizontal orientation to put images beside each other. However, is there  way that the images can automatically go to the next line incase they dont fit due to screen size?

I just dont want small screen (or small densities) to truncate my images
Thank you

Comment: In plain Java you'd be lookin for a `FlowLayout`. Unfortunately, Android does not offer such a layout/widget. There is, however, [a port available](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout) that you might be interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout and reorder images via code according to image sizes and space.

OR

Extend GridLayout and make your own implementation of it.

This is not possible in LinearLayout as it is.